# Convert an image between PIL to OpenCV Python 3.6.3

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

How would one pass an image from PIL to OpenCV without having to save and reload it?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('path/to/pic.jpg')
#modify picture using PIL
img.save('path/to/pic.jpg')
img = cv2.imread("pic.jpg")
```

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for `Python 3.7.3`:

```
from PIL import Image
from cv2 import cvtColor, COLOR_BGR2RGB
from numpy import array

# get the image path
img_path = 'images/test.jpg'
img_rgb = cvtColor(array(Image.open(img_path)), COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the **bytes** and construct your numpy array (cv2 is internally using numpy too to store their data).

```
def imageToNumpy():
    with Image.open('dark.jpg') as img:         
        nparray = np.fromstring(img.tobytes(), dtype=np.uint8)
        nparray = nparray.reshape((img.size[1], img.size[0], img.layers))  
    return nparray


cv2.imwrite("testme.png", imageToNumpy() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html)

Untested code:

```
temp_file = TemporaryFile()
with open('path/to/pic.jpg', 'wb') as f:
   temp_file.write(f)
   temp_file.seek(0)

pil_img = Image.open(temp_file)
cv_img = cv2.imread(temp_file)
```